# HBITMAP from bits

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

in big shortcut I'm trying to write program which draws bitmaps from received via NamedPipe bitmaps from another application.

I'm sending separately BITMAPINFO structure and bitmap bits which I obtain from GetBitmapBits function. On receiving side I have a thread which overwrite using HeapAlloc two global pointers: pbmi_paint (which points BITMAPINFO) and lpBitmapBits_paint (for bitmap bits). Data in pbmi_paint always seems to be legit. Then i try to draw this with this code in WndProc:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    if(pbmi_paint != NULL && lpBitmapBits_paint != NULL) {
        hBitmap = CreateDIBitmap( hdc,&(pbmi_paint->bmiHeader), CBM_INIT,(LPVOID) lpBitmapBits_paint,pbmi_paint,DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bitmap), &bitmap);

        hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        oldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        SelectObject(hdcMem, oldBitmap);
        DeleteDC(hdcMem);
        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    }       
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
```

Then I get nothing (black rectangle). I checked bitmap.bmBits and it equals 0x00000000 (NULL, another members of bitmap struct are set up correctly).
I also tried to set up bitmap.bmBits manually in this way:

```
case WM_PAINT:
 hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    if(pbmi_paint != NULL && lpBitmapBits_paint != NULL) {
        hBitmap = CreateDIBitmap( hdc,&(pbmi_paint->bmiHeader), CBM_INIT,(LPVOID) lpBitmapBits_paint,pbmi_paint,DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bitmap), &bitmap);
        bitmap.bmBits = lpBitmapBits_paint;
        hBitmap1 =  CreateBitmapIndirect(&bitmap);
        hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        oldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap1);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        SelectObject(hdcMem, oldBitmap);
        DeleteDC(hdcMem);
        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        DeleteObject(hBitmap1);
    }
```

And after this hBitmap1 is NULL. So my question is why I can not use pointer to data in CreateDIBitmap or CreateBitmapIndirect? Do these functions check if data is valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitmaps in Windows are a mess, particularly DDB (Device Dependent Bitmap). If possible I always prefer to use DIBs (Device Independent Bitmaps). They are much easier to use and int modern hardware there shoudn't be any noticeable performance difference.

A DIB is created with the function [`CreateDIBSection()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and the pixel data is done independently. Something like this:

```
void *pixels;
HBITMAP hBmp = CreateDIBSection(NULL, pbmi_paint, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &pixels, NULL, 0);
memcpy(pixels, lpBitmapBits_paint, NumBytesInBitmapBits_paint);
```